# How to prevent my Windows 7 to hang when running intense calculations on all cores?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, cpu-usage

When i am using all my 4 cores, its **really slow** to open any folders or even right click on desktop, or open any programs, and so on.

Is there any way to prevent my Windows 7 from using 100% of my CPU and use instead 99% so theres something left for my Windows 7 to run with?

Or any other ideas ? I dont remember this kind happening on older Windows machines, even when i had just one core back then, it never froze my system like this.

I had same kind problem when i used SSD harddrive (or broken HDD), but now i dont, and its not about that, my programs arent writing on disk at all, just bare calculations.

Comment: What program are you running? That helps with troubleshooting.

Comment: @surfasb, my own.

Comment: @surfasb, actually it doesnt matter what the program is, i simply want to avoid all possible freezing when all my cores are using 100% and the windows desktop etc doesnt get any of it. so i just want to give the windows a little CPU **always**

Answer (score 2):

i can think of a few - firstly manually assign affinities to those tasks from task manager, or alternately reduce their priority to below normal.

The first lets you have a core free. the second allows tasks with regular priority to happen first.

Comment: i was thinking of something more automated method.

Comment: To automate the priority that a program runs at simply.  use the Start command in a tiny batch file .  like this . start /B "" /low "c:\program files\whatever program.exe" Make a shortcut to the .bat file, then click that shortcut to start the program.

Comment: i was thinking a bit more automated system, so it wouldnt allow any program to exceed 100% except windows own stuff

Comment: Yes, that is how I interpreted your original question.  There are many parts and pieces to the windows stuff, and I for one would hope that MS themselves never decides to finish thier takeover of my system :-)   You Can mess with the OS to do that in various ways, but it leads to many issues and problems.  The methods presented will work mostly , and will not cause any problems, and are very simple.